# How can I get metasploit for 18.04?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, customization, metasploit, pentesting

Just got Ubuntu mini 18.04 and I'm planning on making it specially designed for hacking & pentesting. I've got the basics such as nmap and some custom scripts but I'm wondering how to get the god of hacking tools - metasploit. Please don't just say "just use kali or blackarch" because I want this to be custom. All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rapid7/metasploit-omnibus/master/config/templates/metasploit-framework-wrappers/msfupdate.erb > msfinstall
```

set permission :

```
chmod 755 msfinstall
```

Then:

```
./msfinstall
```

Create and initialize the msf database.

```
msfdb init
```